# replace first and last occurrence of / with empty

Tags: javascript, regex

for `/add/id/`

should give `add/id`

I tried using `replace()`, but it replaces only the first occurrence. Is there a way to replace both first and last occurrence of / in a single step?

Comment: Try `str = str.replace(/\//g,' ').trim().split(' ').join('/');`

Comment: @HassanImam Though if Gutam's string ever contains spaces, he should not do this. Hassan, I'm curious why you replaced first time, but then split and join? Why not just run another replace after you trimmed, to revert back?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yeah, in case of spaces, it will not work. Yeah, you are right I should have used replace once I trimmed it.

Comment: What would be the expected behaviour if the input has more slashes, say `///add/id///`? It might not matter in your particular circumstances but the solution would be slightly different depending on whether you'd want to remove all the slashes at the beginning and end or literally just the first and last.

Answer (score 2):

You can `split()` your string on `/` and then slice the array leaving the first and last values and then join on `/`

```js
var str = '/add/id/';
const result = str.split('/').slice(1, -1).join('/');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it using regular expression that matches everything apart from first and last character, into a capturing group, then the replacement is just the group:

```
 str.replace(/^.(.*).$/, "$1")
```

This regex means :

```
/    Start of regex delimiter in js
^    Start of input
.    Match one character - first slash in your input
(    Start a capturing group
.*   Match zero or more of any character
)    End the capturing group
.    Match another single character - the last slash in your input
$    End of regular expression input
/    End delimiter for regex string in js
```

It is the greedy quantifier .* that does all the work. It consumes all of the rest of the characters in the input, after the first one, then starts spitting characters back out until the rest of the patten is satisfied. Because the pattern calls for one char to be matched at the end, it means the capturing group will effectively contain everything in between the first and last character

Comment: I would upvote this answer if you have given a regular expression that matched leading and trailing `/` characters instead of any character.

Comment: I specifically didn't do this because I didn't see the point in making the regex harder to read (the forward slash has to be escaped to stop js thinking it's a delimiter) when the input is clearly known and well formed.. I appreciate you could argue "maybe not all of his inputs have a slash at the end, and this might remove chars unexpectedly" but we can't really get into debating hypothetical situations outside of what an OP has posted, because there are millions of them

Comment: this will replace `any start or end character except for line terminators` but he wants to replace `/` only.

Comment: @Hitmands his input starts and ends with a slash, and nothing about the question indicates that it is ever otherwise. Stop inventing problems, and go for the simple solution, not the perfect one

Answer (score -1):

To get index for the first occurrence use: `string.indexOf("/")`;
For the last occurrence use: `string.lastIndexOf("/")`;

Use `string.replaceAt()` to complete the task (refer to the implementation sample at Git: https://gist.github.com/AdamBrodzinski/4010249 ):

```
string.replaceAt(string.indexOf("/"), "");
string.replaceAt(string.lastIndexOf("/"), "");
```

You can chain the replace operations to produce compact code:

```
string.replaceAt(string.lastIndexOf("/"), "").replaceAt(string.indexOf("/"), "");
```

Another possible option would be using `slice()` function.

In case the "/" char has a fixed position (first/last pertinent to your example), then the simplest solution would be using `substring()` function essentially removing first and last char as shown below:

```
string.substring(1, string.length-1);
```

Alternatively, you may use Regex, but this method will provide a better performance

Hope this may help.

Comment: Please share `replaceAt`.

Comment: @CaiusJard It depends on the complexity of the original string; in certain cases the difference could be significant. Rgds,

Comment: @HassanImam Thanks for your input but could you please clarify that "sharing" method? Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell Please share link of 'replaceAt' function.

Comment: @HassanImam Thanks again. There are plenty of sample implementations (link provided), but it seems a simple substring() solution may suffice the task. Rgds,

Comment: @alexbell I'd have said it depends more on the complexity of the regex, not the string - this case suits a very simple regex, and I've a doubt that it will ever cost more cpu time than the brain time that is spent by Developer A making the code more lengthy plus brain time of Developer B coming along to understand and maintain lengthier code..

Comment: this will replace the first occurrence of `/` but he wants to replace it only if it is at `index 0` (same for `lastIndexOf`).

Comment: @Hitmands Thanks for your comments. I've provided several alternative solutions, so OP can select whichever is the best fit. Rgds,

Comment: @Hitmands where exactly does the OP say that? You're inventing requirements that have never been stated

Comment: `/add/id/` should give `add/id`

Answer (score -1):

replace all occurrences `g` of `^\/` or `\/$`.

```js
const input = '/add/id/';

const re = /^\/|\/$/g;

console.log({
  input,
  output: input.replace(re, '')
});
```